# Нет прав доступа к файлу

Tags: php, linux

На сервере веду логи событий, при попытке записать лог в файл, php отдает ошибку `failed to open stream: Permission denied ...`  пробовал выдать полные права и поменять владельца, но ошибка остается та же самая. Что еще может ограничивать права, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: 1. Посмотрите права на все каталоги выше, для `/var/log/log.log` это будут `/var` и `/var/log`. Должен быть флаг `x` - для каталогов он дает возможность просмотра содержимого. 2. Также - работает Selinux ?

Answer (score 1):

От какого пользователя идет запись в лог? Покажите результаты команды ls -la ИмяЛога

Выставьте chmod 777 для файла, проверьте еще раз. Не забудьте после теста вернуть права для файла в нужное русло.

Comment: Никогда не используйте права 777, и не советуйте другим!

Comment: Я знаю это, у человека ситуация, которая требует выяснить, в чем проблема, ответ был с расчетом на то, что это и так очевидно. Сейчас дополню ответ, спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно знать от какого пользователя запускается php - обычно это пользователь: `www-data`

Поменяйте владельца файла на нужного пользователя `chown www-data /path/to/logfile` и проверяйте запись в файл.